# make a db name a variable in webSQL

Tags: sql, json, database, web-sql

I'm looking for a solution to make the database name of my webSQL query a variable , if it's possible, I have not found any clue yet.
I'm working on transformation of .json to webSql.

Here's some parts of my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    CreateTable();
        $.getJSON('dataMultiTable.json',function(data){

            console.log(data);

                $.each(data.People, function(index, People){
                    InsertData(baseUtilisateur,People.nom,People.prenom,People.tel,People.email,People.adresse);    
                });

        });
        return false;

});
function CreateTable() { 
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS baseUtilisateur (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, prenom TEXT, nom TEXT,tel TEXT,email TEXT,adresse TEXT)");
    });
  }
function InsertData(entryNom,entryPrenom,entryTel,entryMail,entryAdresse) {

var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO baseUtilisateur (prenom,nom,tel,email,adresse) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    db.transaction(function(tx) {

      tx.executeSql(insertStatement,[entryPrenom,entryNom,entryTel,entryMail,entryAdresse]);
    });
  }
```

So can I make the 'baseUtilisateur' a variable ?
I already have tried to use the ? , [] which is used in the insert into query for the values but it doesnt work.

Thanks,

Comment: You wrote baseUtilisasteur instead of baseUtilisateur